# How do I remove this ring around the via?

Tags: pcb, altium, bga

I am wondering what this is this ring around the via and how do I remove it?

I am using Altium 20.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove what exactly? I think the gray circle just indicates where the drill is centered, green is the annular copper ring, and the blue/teal is the open isolation, with black **thermal relief spokes** connecting it to the surrounding copper pour (netname +CPU_VDD). Removing thermal relief will have an effect on the manufacturability of the board, because the large copper area will draw heat away from the via during soldering, potentially causing assembly defects.

Comment: @MarkU So I am using these vias with a BGA with a 0.8mm pitch, I am worried that they will interfere with the other pins just because of how big these vias expand out. Is there a way that I can reduce the size of the green and teal outside of the gray ring?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called a "microvia", not sure if that is industry-standard name or if it applies to Altium. The pad stacks that were used for 1970's era DIP parts are not a good size fit for BGA, as you have observed.

Comment: Do you know how I could set up "Microvia"? The current size that I am using now is .25mm for the hole size and .45mm for the via diameter.

Comment: I don't know the dimensions offhand. Usually when our CAD team does a BGA layout for a new package size, they talk with the PCB vendor to make sure the design is manufacturable; part of the process of requesting quotes. Only the PCB vendor can tell you how much to budget for dimensional tolerance (layer registration). There's also a minimum drill hole size that a mechanical drill can achieve, smaller than that size hole would require a more expensive laser drill process, which not every vendor supports.

Comment: You can't remove anything. Your PCB manufacturer may allow you to reduce the hole diameter, or the pad diameter. Talk to them. This may cost you however; drilling small holes is expensive, and pad diameter must be large enough to allow for misalignment between layers.

Comment: Can you also share the "Properties" dialog for this via?

Comment: @ThePhoton I have updated the question, providing the properties and preferences of the via, I also tried to use micro vias and I still get the ring. I am using the recommended via size for this pitch. I am worried that those worried that this will affect manufacturing. I have also added an image of what the via looks like with the fan out.